# NestJs - How to use the same schema & collection for different connections?

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

I need to establish two different connections to the same mongodb, but with different connection options (**poolSize**, **readPreference**, etc.) of course with different connectionName. The **MongooseModules** are imported in the **AppModule**

```
@Module({
  imports: [CustomMongooseDynamicModule, CustomSlavegooseDynamicModule, ...],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then in some other module I would like to use the same schema/model for each of these connections - note that collection names are the same, connection names are different

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: "ABC", schema: AbcSchema }], "main"),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: "ABC", schema: AbcSchema }], "slave"),
  ],
  controllers: [SomeController],
  providers: [SomeService]
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

**The question is** - how can I inject the model into the **SomeService** for **'main'** & **'slave'** connection separately?

```
@InjectModel('ABC') private readonly abcModel: Model<AbcDocument>,
@InjectModel('ABC') private readonly abcSlaveModel: Model<AbcDocument>, ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the second parameter `connectionName` if you look at the @InjectModel decorator declaration.

```
export declare const InjectModel: (model: string, connectionName?: string | undefined) => (target: object, key: string | symbol, index?: number | undefined) => void;
```

So you need to pass the connection name as the second parameter.

```
@InjectModel('ABC', 'main') private readonly abcModel: Model<AbcDocument>,
@InjectModel('ABC', 'slave') private readonly abcSlaveModel: Model<AbcDocument>, ???
```